# monotonicity of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: monotone-functions

If $f$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$, and $x_1,x_2>0$, if $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is monotonic increasing, prove that $f(x_1+x_2)\geq f(x_1)+f(x_2)$.

I suppose it has something to do with starting from $x_1\leq x_1+x_2$ and $x_2\leq x_1+x_2$, but I can't really figure it out-- can anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WLOG we may assume $x_1\geq x_2$. Then we have $$\frac{f(x_1+x_2)}{x_1+x_2}\geq \frac{f(x_1)}{x_1}$$
$$\implies f(x_1+x_2)\geq f(x_1)+x_2\frac{f(x_1)}{x_1}\geq f(x_1)+x_2\frac{f(x_2)}{x_2} = f(x_1)+f(x_2)$$which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: what do you mean by bellow?

Comment: You are upperaverageintelligence (+1).

Comment: Your answer replaces $f(x_2)$ with $f(x_1)$ without any explanation. How did you get from $\frac{x_1}{x_2}f(x_2)$ to $\frac{x_1}{x_2}f(x_1)$

Comment: sorry I believe I've fixed the problem.

Comment: Nice. I'd still add one more step showing the substituting in of $\frac{f(x_2)}{x_2}$ for $\frac{f(x_1)}{x_1}$ before cancelling out the $x_2$'s.

Comment: is that more clear?

Comment: Yes. Perfect now. Thanks.